# How to run shell script within shell script with fixed arguments

Tags: bash, parameters

I have a simple script that creates a loop around another script and directly gives the parameters and arguments to that script - here comes the loop into play since the script is supposed to run over several files. The way I wrote it it's currently not working so how should I attach these parameters? I'm fairly new to bash so any help will be appreciated a lot!

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH="xx.sh"
for x in {001..031}; do
"$SCRIPT_PATH" /data/raw/"$x"_AE data/processed/"$x"_AE 5 --info
done
```

Comment: Is xx.sh in your current directory? What if you do `./xx.sh`?

Comment: Please describe what is meant by "it is not working".  What is the error message you are getting?  You can trace your script with `bash -x yourscript.sh`.

Comment: Try to call xx.sh directly and don't quote the variable, so `xx.sh /data/raw/${x}_AE data/processed/${x}_AE 5 --info`

Comment: Also, put `set -x` after `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I incorporated especially the comments on the for loop since the error was in there - and it works perfectly well now!

Answer (score 0):

1. There may have a syntax issue in your script, the first path is starting with '/' (/data/raw/...) so it is absolute, but it is NOT the case of the second one data/processed/...; is is intentional?
2. Ensure there is NO directory/path issue (where is xx.sh located ?)
3. Ensure the user who launches the script has access permissions on /data directories and sub-directories

Let me know if it fixes your issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I eventually found out the problem was in the for loop and after incorporating the other comments it works well.